# unable to override a method in Scala

Tags: scala

I have 2 traits and 1 class.

In trait `A`, both methods `A1` and `A2` need implementation

```
scala> trait A {
     | def A1
     | def A2
     | }
defined trait A
```

In trait `B`, Even though `A1` is implemented here, it needs to be abstract as it uses super and it still needs implementation in instance class. `A2` is implemented

```
scala> trait B extends A {
     | abstract override def A1 = {
     | super.A1
     | }
     | def A2 = println("B")
     | }
defined trait B
```

Now I have a class `C` which defines `A1` (not related to previous traits)

```
scala> class C {
     | def A1 = println("C")
     | }
defined class C
```

Now I want to create object `C1` which should be of type `C` but I want some functionality of `B` as well (say `A2`). But it doesn't compile. How can I use `A2` from `B` in `C`? I supposed that it would work because `C` has implemented `A1` already.

```
scala> val c1 = new C with B
<console>:13: error: overriding method A1 in class C of type => Unit;
 method A1 in trait B of type => Unit cannot override a concrete member without a third member that's overridden by both (this rule is designed to prevent ``accidental overrides'')
       val c1 = new C with B
                    ^
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error stops you for doing this to prevent "accidental overrides". Your `A1` method is defined in both `B` and `C`, but to the compiler, they are unrelated and just happen to have the same type signature. You therefore have to provide an overriding implementation of this method in your object. You can do it like this:

```
val c1 = new C with B {
  override def A1 = ??? // Add your implementation here.
}
```